# TestFlight to Production

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a large list of users using my beta app via TestFlight. Will their apps get updated via the AppStore when I go live? Just wondering if there's an automated way to have my beta testers get the production app without having to uninstall and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is. They would have to install the app from the app store manually.

Answer (score 0):

App won't get updated automatically, there is one way you can do is check the version number of current build & need a web service call verify that higher version is available or not available then ask user to update the App.

```
if let text = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
            print(text)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I already have something similar implemented. Wasn't sure if App Store would automatically update my app.